# JSON.parse(this.response) String issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, string, web-inspector

I have a working CORS FaaS, that returns appropriately to GET requests.

My local URL Trigger output looks something like this:

```
{"error":false,"string":5.0X5.0=25.0,"answer":25.0}
```

I get the Browser error: "Unexpected token at X in JSON"

In the front-end, I believe the issue to be escaping string in this line:

```
var j = JSON.parse(this.response);
```

Comment: You should show more code

Comment: your output is not valid JSON.  It should be something like: `{"error":false,"string":"5.0X5.0=25.0","answer":25.0}`

Comment: There are JSON validators available online... why not use them?

Answer (score 1):

The string returned by the endpoint is not valid JSON

```json
{"error":false,"string":5.0X5.0=25.0,"answer":25.0}
```

The "string" value is missing quotes around. It should be:

```json
{"error":false,"string":"5.0X5.0=25.0","answer":25.0}
```